# tracking two fingers with TouchesMoved

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, multi-touch

Suppose I have two fingers touching iPhone's screen but just one is moving.

TouchesMoved will just show one finger (event).

How do I know which of the two fingers TouchesMoved is referring too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that it is possible to do what I want. Just check Stanford's CS193P course on iTunesU.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if you think about it there's no "definitive" way to associate one finger with one touch point.  It isn't, after all, that your fingers have globally unique id's that the iPhone has the ability to sample.

What you need to do is keep a record of the "prior" locations, which is useful for managing pinches and other things anyway - and tag each finger based on the proximity to the prior touches set.

Comment: thanks, but I discovered there's a way to track fingers...
http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2008/11/24/snippet-pinch-and-stretch/

Answer (score 1):

First, enable multitouch on your `UIView`:

```
self.multipleTouchEnabled = true
```

Then keep a dictionary for the `UITouch` objects. The same `UITouch` objects gets passed in `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded`:

```
var touchTypes = Dictionary<UITouch, Int>()

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touchObject in touches {
        touchTypes.updateValue(i, forKey: touch as UITouch) //determine i for your own implementation
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let type = touchTypes[touch] //depending on this value, do something
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touchObject in touches {
        touchTypes.removeValueForKey(touchObject as UITouch)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the touches as a [`NSSet *`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/index.html) from the `TouchesBegan` method, you'll need to loop through all the touches and put them into context of your app so that you can identify them later.

It would've been much easier to help you if you described your intent ...

Comment: I have an image that I want to move around. This image can be moved by one finger (one person) or two fingers (two persons). 

Imagine that person A moves his finger from point A1 to A2. If there is a person B, it moves his finger from point B1 to B2.

If just one person is present, then the image is moved the variation between the coordinates of points A1 and A2. If two persons are moving, then the image moves the SUM of the variations of the positions of the two fingers. So, I need to track how much each finger moved.

Comment: I have a similar problem and the `touches` set always contain single object in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> TouchesMoved will just show one finger
>   (event).

but this isn't actually true: as long as two fingers are touching the screen, and at least one of them moves, you'll get a `touchesMoved` with **both** fingers.

if one finger is picked up temporarily, you may get some `touchesMoved` calls with just one finger, so you have to decide what to do about that.